# DELETE FROM table WHERE condition is met in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query that has been working great. I would like to have something similar that would delete a line from `PRC_FIX` when the column `DESCR` in `IM_ITEM` begins with Clearance instead of where `ITEM_VEND_NO = 'GAMES WORK'`.

```
DELETE `PRC_FIX` FROM `PRC_FIX` 
INNER JOIN `IM_ITEM` ON `IM_ITEM`.`ITEM_NO` = `PRC_FIX`.`ITEM_NO` 
                     AND `IM_ITEM`.`ITEM_VEND_NO` = 'GAMES WORK'
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: This was marked as a possible duplicate. I don't know that looking at the suggested duplicate would have helped me because I wouldn't have known how to implement it in this scenario involving 2 tables, but I'm willing to admit that might be my fault due to me being new to SQL.

Comment: `AND IM_ITEM.DESCR LIKE 'Clearance%'`

Comment: BTW, conditions that don't relate the two tables should normally be in the `WHERE` clause, not `ON` (an exception is outer joins).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Barmar. I am still new to SQL and was given this query to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL like search string starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908142/sql-like-search-string-starts-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
DELETE PRC_FIX
  FROM PRC_FIX
 INNER JOIN IM_ITEM
    ON IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO = PRC_FIX.ITEM_NO
 WHERE UPPER(IM_ITEM.DESCR) LIKE 'CLEARANCE%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the wildcard %.

in order to match with this string with different string which begins with "Clearance" you need to use "Clearance%".

Look here: [SQL like search string starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908142/sql-like-search-string-starts-with)

You're fixed code:

```
 DELETE `PRC_FIX` FROM `PRC_FIX` 
    INNER JOIN `IM_ITEM` ON `IM_ITEM`.`ITEM_NO` = `PRC_FIX`.`ITEM_NO` 
                         AND IM_ITEM.DESCR LIKE 'Clearance%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DETELE FROM PRC_FIX WHERE ITEM_NO IN (SELECT ITEM_NO FROM IM_ITEM WHERE ITEM_VEND_NO` = 'GAMES WORK')
```