# Elasticsearch "Did you mean" functionality

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've been implementing an Elasticsearch solution for an ecommerce system in which I'm using the term suggest to try and create a "Did you mean ..." like feature

For misspellings, it works really well

For example, if I search for `hampster` then it comes back suggesting the correct spelling `hamster` which is exactly what I want

The problem comes in when I search for something like `food`, it comes back suggesting `fold` which I don't want it to do

What I'm trying to work out is if there's something built in to Elasticsearch that enables me to see that `food` is a valid term that doesn't need the suggestion

Not sure if this is useful, but here's my query and response (PHP)

```
Array
(
[suggest] => Array
    (
        [spell_check] => Array
            (
                [text] => food
                [term] => Array
                    (
                        [field] => name
                    )

            )

    )

)


Array
(
[took] => 1
[timed_out] => 
[_shards] => Array
    (
        [total] => 5
        [successful] => 5
        [skipped] => 0
        [failed] => 0
    )

[hits] => Array
    (
        [total] => 0
        [max_score] => 0
        [hits] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[suggest] => Array
    (
        [spell_check] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => food
                        [offset] => 0
                        [length] => 4
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => fold
                                        [score] => 0.75
                                        [freq] => 1
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => feed
                                        [score] => 0.5
                                        [freq] => 4
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => four
                                        [score] => 0.5
                                        [freq] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: information is not enough, you should show some code. But i think problem is in your sql. You should update sql. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908166/4459647 you should give % at the end of searched item.

Comment: There is no mention of SQL in the question - it's purely Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually intended behaviour because it caters for possible spelling errors.  There is a score associated with the returned suggested value and more than one item gets returned.  In your case the query for food, assuming you have food related data in your database, will return results.  I am not sure if you are also returning results in the case (or just using ES as some sort of suggestion service) of a hit but your logic could, for example, only make a suggestion in the event of no results returned.  You can also see that "feed" is returned but has a lower score because there is, I assume, also a levenshtein distance applied to calculate the final score.

Comment: I do use Elasticsearch to perform the actual search too but the problem is my main search uses "fuzzyness" so even incorrect spellings will still return results so I can't use that to determine if it's invalid or not. I guess I could run a separate, non fuzzy search just on 1 field which should be nice and quick and use that to determine whether to show suggestions or not. I'll have to experiment. Thanks for the response

Comment: No problem.  The easiest and certainly the least 'expensive' would be to return a list - you could limit to top two or three suggestions.  If you run either similar_text or levenshtein PHP functions on your examples you will see that food and fold are more similar.  The other alternative would be to use an NLP library and set some rules for what might determine what you will pluck from the array.  A bit of work involved there and you might not always get the result you expect either.